# How to use San Francisco Font when converting a description with HTML Markup to NSAttributedString on iOS using Swift

Tags: html, ios, swift, fonts, nsattributedstring

I use this code to convert a description with HTML Markup into a NSAttributedString.

```
func attributedStringFromDescription(description: String, withFontName fontName: String) -> NSAttributedString? {
    let attributedOptions : [String: AnyObject] = [NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType, NSCharacterEncodingDocumentAttribute: NSUTF8StringEncoding]
    let betterDescription = "<br><font face=\"\(fontName)\">" + description + "</font>"
    if let encodedData = betterDescription.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding) {
        return NSAttributedString(data: encodedData, options: attributedOptions, documentAttributes: nil, error: nil)
    }
    return nil
}
```

It works well for the font "Helvetica Neue" in iOS8, because the HTML markup I happen to be working with is very basic and doesn't contain any special fonts or links, etc.

Unfortunately, the font name "San Francisco" doesn't work on iOS 9 beta 5, it just uses the default Times New Roman font.

How can I create an attributedString from a description in iOS 9 using the San Francisco Font?

**Edit 1:**

I've tried replacing better description with

```
let betterDescription = "<html><head><style type=\"text/css\"> body { font-family: -apple-system; } </style></head><body>" + description + "</body></html>"
```

but that didn't seem to help either...

Comment: If you enumerate fonts, do you find the San Francisco font? What's the logs of its name? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8090916/fonts-on-ios-device

Comment: @Larme "San Francisco" is not listed in UIFont.familyNames(),
If i inspect UIFont.systemFontOfSize(UIFont.systemFontSize()) on iOS 9 i see ".SFUIText-Regular"

Comment: I didn't check, but you may get more info there: https://developer.apple.com/fonts/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using this code to log the fonts on iOS 9 reveals that you can use `.SF UI Text` in order to get the new San Francisco font and then you can apply it to your attributed string as well.

```
    let fontFamily = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(UIFont.systemFontSize()).familyName
    print(fontFamily)

    if let attributedString = attributedStringFromDescription(originalDescription, withFontName: fontFamily) {
        myLabel.attributedText = attributedString
    }
```

Comment: Thanks!  This works for the San Francisco font in iOS 9 beta.  Strangely this doesn't work for iOS 8 Helvetica Neue.

Answer (score 0):

BTW: The original question shows the function outdated. With newer versions of swift this works:

```
    func attributedStringFromHtml(_ description: String, withFontName fontName: String) -> NSAttributedString? {
        let htmlString = "<span style=\"font-family: '\(fontName)';\">\(description)</span>"
        guard let data = htmlString.data(using: .utf8) else { return nil }

        // Options for the attributed string
        let options: [NSAttributedString.DocumentReadingOptionKey: Any] = [
            .documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html,
            .characterEncoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue
        ]

        do {
            // Attempt to create an attributed string
            let attributedString = try NSAttributedString(data: data, options: options, documentAttributes: nil)
            return attributedString
        } catch {
            print("Error creating attributed string from HTML: \(error)")
            return nil
        }
    }
```