# Why is using UIControlState.normal on a segmented control causing this crash?

Tags: swift, uisegmentedcontrol

I have a simple `UISegmentedControl` with two segments and I'm trying to customize its appearance.

I'm getting this runtime error:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception >'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSNull renderingMode]:  unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x112156f08'

```
@IBOutlet weak var sortController: UISegmentedControl!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    styleSortController()

    // other setup code

}

func styleSortController() {
    let titleAttributes: [String: Any] = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.white, NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "AvenirNext-Demi", size: CGFloat(14.0)) as Any]
    let selectedTitleAttributes: [String: Any] = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.white,
                                                  NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "AvenirNext-DemiBold", size: CGFloat(14.0)) as Any]

    // this line causes it to crash
    sortController.setTitleTextAttributes(titleAttributes, for: UIControlState.normal)

    // but this line works, no problem
    sortController.setTitleTextAttributes(selectedTitleAttributes, for: UIControlState.selected)
}
```

caused by the line seen above where I first try to set a title text attribute (note that the second line setting an attribute works just fine).

According to Apple's documentation, I should be able to use any valid `UIControlState` and `UIControlState.normal` sure seems valid so I'm really confused about why this is happening.

What could this line be causing me trouble?

Comment: Check that `UIFont(name: "AvenirNext-Demi", size: CGFloat(14.0))` is not nil. I think that ` sortController.setTitleTextAttributes(selectedTitleAttributes, for: UIControlState.normal)` work. I strongly suspect the font attribute to be an issue not the state.

Comment: selectedTitleAttributes Dictionary type is wrong

Comment: `let selectedTitleAttributes: [NSAttributedString.Key: Any]`

Comment: @LeoDabus - I'm not sure what you're trying to say. I'll need more words.

Comment: Change your dictionary type to the type I commented above

Comment: @LeoDabus - I changed it and the compilers complained, essentially telling me I needed to cast my keys like so: `let titleAttributes: [NSAttributedString.Key: Any] = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName as NSString: UIColor.white, NSFontAttributeName as NSString: UIFont(name: "AvenirNext-Medium", size: CGFloat(13.0)) as Any]` Thoughts?

Comment: @Larme - Thank you, Larme. It turns out that "AvenirNext-Demi" isn't valid. I changed it to "AvenirNext-Medium" and now it works.

Comment: @LeoDabus - The compiler is forcing me to cast it as NSString.

Comment: Add the key type followed by a dot and check the autocomplete options to select the desired key such as .foregroundColor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let titleAttributes: [String: Any] = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.white, 
                                      NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "AvenirNext-Demi", size: CGFloat(14.0)) as Any]
let selectedTitleAttributes: [String: Any] = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.white,
                                              NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "AvenirNext-DemiBold", size: CGFloat(14.0)) as Any]
```

Before saying it's the `UIControlState` issue, you need to do:

```
sortController.setTitleTextAttributes(selectedTitleAttributes, for: UIControlState.normal)
```

In other words, use the same working sample (the one for `.selected`)

It should create the same error crash.

Then you'll find that the culprit is `UIFont(name: "AvenirNext-Demi", size: CGFloat(14.0))`, it returns nil.

So the font name is not a valid one.

You can iterate through your Font to list it ([see this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8090916/fonts-on-ios-device)) and find the correct one.
It's a "usual one", so you can open *Font Book.app*, find it, and check the Post script name of it. Not all font in macOS are in iOS, but that's the case for that one.

[image]

You'll get: *AvenirNext-Regular*, *AvenirNext-Medium*, *AvenirNext-UltraLight*, *AvenirNext-Italic*, *AvenirNext-MediumItalic*, *AvenirNext-UltraLightItalic*, *AvenirNext-DemiBold*, *AvenirNext-Bold*, *AvenirNext-Heavy*, *AvenirNext-DemiBoldItalic*, *AvenirNext-BoldItalic*, *AvenirNext-HeavyItalic*.

There is no *AvenirNext-Demi*.

So use the one you think fit more your need.

I recommend if you use custom font to install them in your Mac. It's easy to checkout the postscript name of the font that way.

Comment: Thanks, Larme. I didn't know I could check for valid font names that easily. I was digging through menus in IB so that's going to be quite helpful as well.

Answer (score 0):

First problem I see is that lot of code you wrote had been renamed in Swift 4. Attributes format [String: Any] is no longer supported. You have to use [NSAttributedString.Key: Any].

For example: *NSForegroundColorAttributeName --> NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor*

Second, font AvenirNext hasn't any style "Demi", it has just "DemiBold".

```
let titleAttributes: [NSAttributedString.Key: Any] = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.white, NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont(name: "AvenirNext-DemiBold", size: CGFloat(14.0)) as Any]
let selectedTitleAttributes: [NSAttributedString.Key: Any] = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.white, NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont(name: "AvenirNext-DemiBold", size: CGFloat(14.0)) as Any]
```

Comment: What do you mean when you say 'renamed'?

Comment: In Swift 4 `NSForegroundColorAttributeName` is now `NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor`. But you don't seem to use Swift 4.